# Find incoming symlinks

Tags: find, files, symlink

In Linux, what is the best way to find all symbolic links that point to a given file (regardless of whether the symlink is relative or absolute)? I realize this will require scanning the whole filesystem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU `find` has the `-samefile` test. According to the man page:

> ```
> -samefile name
>     File refers to the same inode as name. When -L is in 
>     effect, this can include symbolic links.
> ```

```
$ find -L / -samefile /path/to/file
```

This will find all links to `/path/to/file`, which includes hard links and the file itself. If you only want symlinks, you can individually test the results of `find` (`test -L`).

You should read up on what the effects of `-L` are and ensure that it won't cause you any problems with your search.

Note: While the documentation says it looks for files with the same inode number, it does appear to work across filesystems.

e.g. /home and /tmp are separate filesystems

```
$ touch ~/testfile
$ ln -s ~/testfile /tmp/foo
$ ln -s /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
$ mkdir /tmp/x
$ ln -s ~/testfile /tmp/x/baz
$ find -L /tmp -samefile ~/testfile
/tmp/bar
/tmp/foo
/tmp/x/baz
```

Note how this is returning /tmp/bar, which is a symlink to /tmp/foo, which is a symlink to ~/testfile. If you only wanted to find direct symlinks to your target file, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the shortest way would be:

```
target="/usr/bin/firefox"    # change me
dir="/usr/bin"               # change me
realtarget="$(realpath "$target")"
for file in $(find "$dir" -print); do
    realfile="$(realpath "$file")"
    test "$realfile" = "$realtarget" && echo "$file"
done
```

But it's not very efficient.

If you don't have `realpath`, install it, e.g. `apt-get install realpath`.  You could also use `stat -N` or `ls -l` or `pwd -P` to emulate `realpath`, but those ways are harder.

Also, the above example won't handle file names with spaces in it properly.  Here's a better way to do it.  Note that `IFS=$'\n'` requires `bash` or `zsh`.

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
target="/usr/bin/firefox"    # change me
dir="/usr/bin"               # change me
realtarget="$(realpath "$target")"
find "$dir" -print | while read -r file; do
    realfile="$(realpath "$file")"
    test "$realfile" = "$realtarget" && echo "$file"
done
IFS="$OIFS"
```